# What are the steps to port a Flash game to Mac OS X dmg / App Store and iOS App Store?

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, flash, iad

I've developed a Flash game that I want to publish for Mac OS X and iOS (iPad). The game is composed of multiple SWF files that I want to be nicely packaged when end users download it either from my site (as dmg or pkg installer) or from App Store. I also might start selling my game on Mac App Store and iOS App Store but before that I might consider running some ads. For ads, my only option seems to be the Apple's iAd advertising platform if I go with App Store, so I'll have to layer ads over the flash content somehow. Ideally, users wouldn't need to install any third-party software in order to play the game on Mac.

I know this is possible. There are numerous examples of this. The most prominent is Machinarium game, which was developed in Flash and later ported to Mac and iOS. I just don't know how they did it. I already have some basic knowledge of Xcode and Objective-C.

So which steps should I follow to port my Flash game to Mac OS X dmg / App Store and iOS App Store, perhaps allowing for iAds?

Comment: You [can](http://mgrenier.me/2011/02/flash-to-unity-part-1/) port Flash to Unity. Then, build iOS game using [Unity](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/iphone-GettingStarted.html)

Comment: Use AIR (7 more to go).

Comment: @skinnyTOD Will I be able to run iAds with AIR?

Comment: Come on @DesmondHume, show some effort: this took 2 clicks to find: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/iad-ane-ios.html

Comment: @skinnyTOD I was just passing by, interesting topic.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, publishing on AppStore is not permitted for software written in languages that are not ObjectiveC.

You can create a Flash projector, presumably an .app file, then put external SWFs in that package, and then use some DMG-maker to publish it on your website.

Comment: This is simply not true. Many games has been sucessfully ported to App Store and Machinarium is one of them.

Comment: Probably, since they are packed to a projector (presumably written in a native language), Apple accepts them.
I had some Java apps rejected as they were not native.

Comment: http://intransitione.com/blog/take-java-to-app-store/
If you pack them to a native bundle, they accept them.